# count a json file

Tags: json, extjs, count

I want to display the count of records in a json file. The json file is for example test.json and i want to display the number of records in my extjs file.

I can't get it to work but it sounds easy. Anyone with an idea?

This is what i tried:

```
var jsonData = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
  url: 'test.json',
  root: 'ritas',
});
alert(jsonData.length);
```

The alert will show me "undefined".

When I try a test case like this

```
var jsonData = [{a:1},{b:2},{c:3}];
alert(jsonData.length);
```

the alert will show `3`.

Comment: Please post some of your code. What have you tried? What did you expect to happen? What actually happened?

Answer (score 1):

The `Ext.data.JsonStore` class does not have a `length` property. Instead, use the `getCount()` method of the JsonStore to get the number of cached records:

```
var jsonData = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
  url: 'test.json',
  root: 'ritas',
  fields: [ 'field1', 'field2' ] // record property names go here
});
alert(jsonData.getCount());
```

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonStore-method-getCount

This store is configured to consume JSON in the following format:

```
{
    ritas: [
        {field1: 'field1Value', field2: 'field2Value'}, // record 1
        {field1: 'field1Value2', field2: 'field2Value2'} // record 2
    ]
}
```

Is your server returning an object in this format?

Comment: See my edit. Are you specifying the `fields` config for the store? Does the object returned from the server match the store configuration?

Comment: i use a model for the store. But still got 0

Comment: If possible, post your model and the object returned from the server.